# Why I can't invoke lambda in the Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to invoke a Int value when I click on the each tab but I have an error. I used  `LaunchEffect()` and `Coroutine scope` but it's not solved. how can I fix it?

**Screen code:**

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun Tabs(
    pagerState: PagerState,
    modifier: Modifier,
    state: MyJobsState,
    onTabSelected: @Composable (tabPage: Int) -> Unit
) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    ScrollableTabRow(
        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
        indicator = { tabPositions ->
            TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions),
                height = 0.dp,
            )
        },
        edgePadding = 0.dp,
        divider = {}
    ) {
        state.items?.forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
            Tab(
                text = {
                    Text(
                        text = state.items[index].title ?: "")
                },
                selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                    }
                    onTabSelected.invoke(index)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**I get this error:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onTabSelected` is marked as `@Composable`, that's why you can't invoke it inside `onClick`.

You can only invoke `@Composable` inside an other `@Composable`, not in side effects. Remove this annotation, and you probably need to redesign the view which is using `Tabs`.

You're doing the same mistake again: `onTabSelected` is a side effect. You can't add composable views to the view hierarchy inside side effects.

Instead, you should use a state variable, and change the view depending on this state, e.g.:

```
var selectedTab by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

ScrollableTabRow(
    selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
    indicator = { tabPositions ->
        TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
            modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions),
            height = 0.dp,
        )
    },
    edgePadding = 0.dp,
    divider = {}
) {
    state.items?.forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
        Tab(
            text = {
                Text(
                    text = state.items[index].title ?: "")
            },
            selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
            onClick = {
                selectedTab = index
            }
        )
    }
}

when (selectedTab) {
    0 -> {
        FirstView()
    }
    1 -> {
        SecondView()
    }
}
```

You can find more info about state in Compose in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.

Comment: If I remove the @Composable I can't use the callback value: https://ufile.io/20ellc7p

Comment: @saeednoshadi see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @Composable from your `onTabSelected` parameter. You can't call composables directly from a click event or any other non-composable function.